# detect email sent js into mail html

Tags: jquery, html-email, show-hide, cc

when i send a mail to a list contacts of cc i want show/hide dynamically content for each particular email. i send a html mail, and i can put js and jquery ( i think).

this would be the code:

```
<p> this show to all people </p>
<p> this show too to all people </p>
<p class="tohide"> this p hide/show </p>
```

the best way to make it that i thinked it's read the sent mail and show/hide the `<p class="tohide">text to hide</p>` depending on the recipient.

any idea?

Comment: Mail clients usually don't execute Javascript in the mail.

Comment: thx, if i can't make it with js, how make it? i can't send 2 mails

Comment: Even if you could send JS, it would still be the same for all recipients. There's no way for the script to know which recipient is reading it.